# Show 0 for null count

Tags: sql, count, null, sum

I'm trying to summarize some data about our suppliers, but I'm having trouble showing 0 for suppliers with no data. Simplified SQL code:

```
with daterange as

(
select \* from (values (2017),(2018),(2019),(2020),(2021),(2022),(2023)) y(year)
)

select
count(po.purchaseorderpk) 'Total PO'
,daterange.year
,po.SupplierFK

from purchaseorder po
left join daterange on dateRange.year = year(po.ClosedDate)
group by
daterange.year
,po.supplierfk
order by daterange.year, po.supplierfk
```

To limit to just two suppliers for testing, I've tried adding

```
and po.SupplierFK in( 781, 1176)
```

to the left join, as well as

```
where po.SupplierFK = 781 or po.SupplierFK is null or  po.SupplierFK = 1176
```

With the where, I'm getting this result, which is close to what I want:

| Total PO | year | SupplierFK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 11 | NULL | 781 |
| 5 | NULL | 1176 |
| 32 | 2018 | 781 |
| 3 | 2018 | 1176 |
| 49 | 2019 | 781 |
| 1 | 2019 | 1176 |
| 28 | 2020 | 781 |
| 3 | 2020 | 1176 |
| 17 | 2021 | 781 |
| 2 | 2021 | 1176 |
| 18 | 2022 | 781 |

I would also expect to get these rows:

| Total PO | year | SupplierFK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017 | 1176 |
| 0 | 2017 | 781 |
| 0 | 2023 | 1176 |
| 0 | 2023 | 781 |

I was under the impression that by making the CTE calendar/tally table and left joining it to my data table, it would force the summary calculations for each year specified, even if 0, but I can't seem to get that result. This is just one of several summary calculations I'll need to do on this data, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the joins matters, a [`left join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) returns all of the records from the left table and the matching records from the right table.

Instead of:

```
from purchaseorder po
left join daterange on dateRange.year = year(po.ClosedDate)
```

Try:

```
from daterange dr
left join purchaseorder po on year(po.ClosedDate) = dr.year
```

You won't get the suppliers, unless there's an intermediate `supplier` table you can join on, but you will see the year.

Something like:

| Total PO | year | SupplierFK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017 | NULL |
| 0 | 2023 | NULL |

If you have a `supplier` table a `cross join` may work as you were expecting.

```
select count(po.purchaseorderpk) 'Total PO', dr.year, s.supplierpk
from daterange dr
cross join supplier s
left join purchaseorder po on year(po.ClosedDate) = dr.year and po.supplierfk = s.supplierpk
group by dr.year, s.supplierpk
```

Comment: You're right, I copied the wrong version of the query here. I had it the way you show, and I get the results you show. I can also left join the Supplier table, but I still get only 1 row of 0 PO's for each "NULL" supplier, instead of 0 PO's for each supplier. How can I get a 0 for each supplier?

Comment: @SleightOHand I've added a `CROSS JOIN` example that should work.

Comment: Yes! I actually put 2 and 2 together browsing other threads, and got it working yesterday with a cross join on the supplier table like you have above. My other sums and counts are working as well. Thank you!